# Calculate remain discount for an amount .

Tags: percentages

Calculate remain discount for an amount .

Hi, i have a number X . So i have to give total 50% discount for the number . Now please see the situation

For `X` first we give `30%` discount . So now the number is `Y` and `Y= X*70/100 .`

Second we have to give the remain discount . But the problem is in this step we have only number Y. and we have to multiply this number by a value so that

```
Y* new_value= X*50/100
```

so please help to get the new value .

So i have to Get new_value. and the real question is `Y*How much percentage=X*50%` . And here `Y=X*70/100`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the new percentage be $n$

Then $Yn=0.7nx=0.5x$, so $n=\frac{5}{7}\approx71.4$%

Comment: i will check this friend